# Sidebar on each side?

Tags: html, css

I know this should be a simple thing, but I have so much coding that I think something may be interfering with this. I'm trying to make a thin sidebar on each side of the content. Maybe used for ads or something.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="content">
    <article>
       This is a test.
    </article>
</div>
    <aside id="space">
        Hello.
    </aside>
```

Is anything wrong with it?

**Edit:**
I know that's not two sidebars. I need to make one work first, haha.

Here's the CSS with it, if it helps any:

```
#content{
    float: left;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 350px;
}
article {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 325px;
    height: 325px;
    width: 660x;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(110,110,110) 5px 5px 100px inset;
}
#space{
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #66CCCC
```

Comment: The HTML is fine but you'll need some CSS...

Comment: And another `<aside>`, at the very least. Can't have two sidebars without, well, two.

Comment: Show us a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem you're having.  I'm sure that with a real example (paired with a complete question), you'll get an answer quickly.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll do that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

**HTML**

```
  <aside id="left">
     left
  </aside>

  <div id="content">
     <article>
         This is a test.
     </article>
  </div>

  <aside id="right">
     right
  </aside>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #left, #content, #right {
     float: left;

      text-align: center;
  }

  #left, #right {
      width: 15%;
      background-color: #eee;
  }

  #content {
      width: 70%;
      background-color: #aaa;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fYFX6/

You can add margins to the sidebars if you want.